# Python pandas dataframe get all combinations of column values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
        colour   points
0         red         1
1      yellow        10
2       black        -3
```

Then I'm trying to do the following algorithm:

```
combos = []
points = []

for i1 in range(len(df)):
  for i2 in range(len(df)):

    colour_main      = df['colour'].values[i1]
    colour_secondary = df['colour'].values[i2]
    combo = colour_main + "_" + colour_secondary

    point1 = df['points'].values[i1]
    point2 = df['points'].values[i2]
    new_points = point1 + point2

    combos.append(combo)
    points.append(new_points)

df_new = pd.DataFrame({'colours': combos,
                       'points': points})

print(df_new)
```

I want to get all combinations and sum points:

- if the colour is used as main I want to sum his value
- if the colour is used as a secondary I want to sum opposite value

Example:

```
red_yellow =  1 + (-10) = -9
red_black  =  1 + ( +3) =  4
black_red  = -3 + ( -1) = -4
```

The output I currently get:

```
         colours  points
0        red_red       2
1     red_yellow      11
2      red_black      -2
3     yellow_red      11
4  yellow_yellow      20
5   yellow_black       7
6      black_red      -2
7   black_yellow       7
8    blac_kblack      -6
```

The output I'm looking for:

```
red_yellow       -9
red_black         4
yellow_red        9
yellow_black     13
black_red        -4
black_yellow    -13
```

I don't know how to apply my logic to this code, also I bet there is a more simplest way to get all combinations without doing two loops, but currently, that's the only thing that comes to my mind.

I would like to:

- get deserved output
- improve the performance in cases when we get like 20 input colours
- remove duplicates like red_red

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a `timeit` comparison of a few alternatives.

```
| method             | ms per loop |
|--------------------+-------------|
| alt2               |        2.36 |
| using_concat       |        3.26 |
| using_double_merge |        22.4 |
| orig               |        22.6 |
| alt                |        45.8 |
```

The `timeit` results were generated using `IPython`:

```
In [138]: df = make_df(20)

In [143]: %timeit alt2(df)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.36 ms per loop
In [140]: %timeit orig(df)
10 loops, best of 3: 22.6 ms per loop
In [142]: %timeit alt(df)
10 loops, best of 3: 45.8 ms per loop
In [169]: %timeit using_double_merge(df)
10 loops, best of 3: 22.4 ms per loop
In [170]: %timeit using_concat(df)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.26 ms per loop
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def alt(df):
    df['const'] = 1
    result = pd.merge(df, df, on='const', how='outer')
    result = result.loc[(result['colour_x'] != result['colour_y'])]

    result['color'] = result['colour_x'] + '_' + result['colour_y']
    result['points'] = result['points_x'] - result['points_y']
    result = result[['color', 'points']]
    return result

def alt2(df):
     points = np.add.outer(df['points'], -df['points'])
     color = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['colour'], df['colour']])
     mask = color.labels[0] != color.labels[1]
     color = color.map('_'.join)
     result = pd.DataFrame({'points':points.ravel(), 'color':color})
     result = result.loc[mask]
     return result

def orig(df):
    combos = []
    points = []

    for i1 in range(len(df)):
        for i2 in range(len(df)):
            colour_main = df['colour'].iloc[i1]
            colour_secondary = df['colour'].iloc[i2]
            if colour_main != colour_secondary:
                combo = colour_main + "_" + colour_secondary

                point1 = df['points'].values[i1]
                point2 = df['points'].values[i2]
                new_points = point1 - point2

                combos.append(combo)
                points.append(new_points)

    return pd.DataFrame({'color':combos, 'points':points})

def using_concat(df):
    """https://stackoverflow.com/a/51641085/190597 (RafaelC)"""
    d = df.set_index('colour').to_dict()['points']
    s = pd.Series(list(itertools.combinations(df.colour, 2)))
    s = pd.concat([s, s.transform(lambda k: k[::-1])])
    v = s.map(lambda k: d[k[0]] - d[k[1]])
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'comb': s.str.get(0)+'_' + s.str.get(1), 'values': v})
    return df2

def using_double_merge(df):
    """https://stackoverflow.com/a/51641007/190597 (sacul)"""    
    new = (df.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.colour, df.colour]))
           .reset_index()
           .drop(['colour', 'points'], 1)
           .merge(df.set_index('colour'), left_on='level_0', right_index=True)
           .merge(df.set_index('colour'), left_on='level_1', right_index=True))

    new['points_y'] *= -1
    new['sum'] = new.sum(axis=1)
    new = new[new.level_0 != new.level_1].drop(['points_x', 'points_y'], 1)
    new['colours'] = new[['level_0', 'level_1']].apply(lambda x: '_'.join(x),1)
    return new[['colours', 'sum']]

def make_df(N):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'colour': np.arange(N), 
                       'points': np.random.randint(10, size=N)})
    df['colour'] = df['colour'].astype(str)
    return df
```

---

The main idea in `alt2` is to use `np.add_outer` to construct an addition table
out of `df['points']`:

```
In [149]: points = np.add.outer(df['points'], -df['points'])
In [151]: points
Out[151]: 
array([[  0,  -9,   4],
       [  9,   0,  13],
       [ -4, -13,   0]])
```

`ravel` is used to make the array 1-dimensional:

```
In [152]: points.ravel()
Out[152]: array([  0,  -9,   4,   9,   0,  13,  -4, -13,   0])
```

and the color combinations are generated with `pd.MultiIndex.from_product`:

```
In [153]: color = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['colour'], df['colour']])
In [155]: color = color.map('_'.join)
In [156]: color
Out[156]: 
Index(['red_red', 'red_yellow', 'red_black', 'yellow_red', 'yellow_yellow',
       'yellow_black', 'black_red', 'black_yellow', 'black_black'],
      dtype='object')
```

A mask is generated to remove duplicates:

```
mask = color.labels[0] != color.labels[1]
```

and then the `result` is generated from these parts:

```
 result = pd.DataFrame({'points':points.ravel(), 'color':color})
 result = result.loc[mask]
```

---

The idea behind `alt` is explained in my [original answer, here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8760b788-6370-46ab-bfca-fc6c23ecd15d/view-source).

Comment: Working @unutbu! Do you know if the performance of this will be better than two loops? What if we get as the input 20 colours?

Comment: @Steve: The double loop is faster for small inputs, such as when `len(df)==20`. The merge performs better than the double loop as `len(df)` gets large. The crossover point on my machine appears to be at about `len(df) == 50`. (I'm using your code, with [Interested Programmer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51640944/190597) correction for comparison).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, was testing all methods and alt2 was the fastest on my machine also. Working as excepted and the performance is very good.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit long-winded, but gets you the output you want:

```
new = (df.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.colour, df.colour]))
       .reset_index()
       .drop(['colour', 'points'], 1)
       .merge(df.set_index('colour'), left_on='level_0', right_index=True)
       .merge(df.set_index('colour'), left_on='level_1', right_index=True))


new['points_x'] *= -1

new['sum'] = new.sum(axis=1)

new = new[new.level_0 != new.level_1].drop(['points_x', 'points_y'], 1)

new['colours'] = new[['level_0', 'level_1']].apply(lambda x: '_'.join(x),1)


>>> new
  level_0 level_1  sum       colours
3  yellow     red   -9    yellow_red
6   black     red    4     black_red
1     red  yellow    9    red_yellow
7   black  yellow   13  black_yellow
2     red   black   -4     red_black
5  yellow   black  -13  yellow_black
```

Answer (score 2):

```
d = df.set_index('colour').to_dict()['points']
s = pd.Series(list(itertools.combinations(df.colour, 2)))
s = pd.concat([s, s.transform(lambda k: k[::-1])])
v = s.map(lambda k: d[k[0]] - d[k[1]])
df2= pd.DataFrame({'comb': s.str.get(0)+'_' + s.str.get(1), 'values': v})

    comb             values
0   red_yellow       -9
1   red_black        4
2   yellow_black     13
0   yellow_red       9
1   black_red        -4
2   black_yellow    -13
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change this line in your code

```
new_points = point1 + point2
```

to this

```
new_points = point1 - point2
```

Comment: for duplicates you could follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/51640933/8663707 answer

Comment: Just simple sign change :O I didn't notice, works but still have to remove duplicates and improve the performance of two loops.